# Hiding Custom Object Records from Administrators

Tags: custom-object, administration, security

I'm working on a managed package, which includes a Custom Object with sensitive information. Is there any way to prevent Salesforce Administrators from seeing the information stored in this object?

See screenshot below, the default view includes some fields I would like to hide. Ideally, an Administrator wouldn't even be able to see the record in the first place, and instead only the Owner of the record would see it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom object record/field visibility will always be available to System Administrators or other users with the appropriate permissions.  You could use encrypted text fields, but these would still be available to users with the "View Encrypted Data" permission.

You could consider a protected hierarchy custom setting instead of a custom object, and build a custom page for editing.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm&language=en

Comment: Thanks for your response @Thomas. Correct me if I'm wrong, but after reading a bit about Custom Settings, it doesn't seem like you can actually modify them from within an Apex controller. You can [retrieve them](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) and read them, but not insert/update them. I realize this wasn't a requirement in my original question though, just noting it here.

Comment: You can perform DML against custom settings using the same syntax as with sobjects.  For the most part, custom settings are very similar to custom objects.  You can even query for a custom setting instead of calling getInstance() (which allows for things like record locking on that custom setting).

Answer (score 1):

Protected Custom settings for managed packages (packages with their own namespace) are not visible to sysadmins and are only available to your application.